# Display manager not working

Tags: dependencies, lightdm, gnome-session

I recently restarted my computer and the Display Manager stopped working.  I got the login screen and as soon as I tried to log in the screen went black.

I went to reinstall `gdm3` but that failed to start the `GUI`. I installed `lightdm` as an alternative and I got further, but when I log in I immediately get `Failed to start session`.

Now I have done some research and the `gnome-session` is not installed.  When I try to install it I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-session : Depends: gnome-session-common (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu2) but 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am running:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2
4.15.0-101-generic #102-Ubuntu
```

In the `seat0-greeter.log` I see a warning about `unity-greeter.vala:217: Failed to start seasion: Session returned error code 1`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can login to the commandline fine with same credentials